Unable to Achieve Bidirectional File Synchronization with SymmetricDS
I'm a newbie here, and I hope I communicate properly. I'm trying to set up SymmetricDS 3.15.9 to replicate a database and a directory for Odoo ERP software, which internally uses a PostgreSQL database and a ./local path to save attached files. After some time testing different software solutions, I found that SymmetricDS could achieve both. I no longer have issues with multimaster database replication, but when setting up bidirectional file replication, it gets stuck on the client node. Did I forget any step to archive the bidirectional file sincronization?
I'm testing the example from version 3.5 (which was a bit tricky to find and get working, because the current documentation only briefly explains file synchronization). I've included the link to download SymmetricDS version 3.5, and the documentation is available at /symmetric-3.5.22/doc/html-single/user-guide.html.
To that example I added a second set of triggers, routers, and trigger routers to achieve bidirectional synchronization because the documentation states that the mechanism is the same.

INSERT INTO sym_file_trigger
  (trigger_id,base_dir,recurse,includes_files,excludes_files,sync_on_create,
   sync_on_modified,sync_on_delete,before_copy_script,after_copy_script,
   create_time,last_update_by,last_update_time)
VALUES ('sync_directory2','/filesync',1,'*.txt',null,1,1,1,
  'targetBaseDir = "/filesync" +
  engine.getParameterService().getExternalId();',null,current_timestamp,'example',
  current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO sym_router
  (router_id,target_catalog_name,target_schema_name,target_table_name,
  source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,
  router_type,router_expression,sync_on_update,sync_on_insert,sync_on_delete,
  create_time,last_update_by,last_update_time)
VALUES
  ('client_2_server',null,null,null,'client','server','default',null,1,1,1,
   current_timestamp,'example',current_timestamp);


INSERT INTO sym_file_trigger_router
 (trigger_id,router_id,enabled,initial_load_enabled,target_base_dir,
  conflict_strategy,create_time,last_update_by,last_update_time)
VALUES
  ('sync_directory2','client_2_server',1,1,'','SOURCE_WINS',current_timestamp,
  'example',current_timestamp);


I'm trying to achieve bidirectional folder synchronization similar to Google Drive, but I'm only getting master-to-client replication. I've tested other file synchronization solutions, but I want to use SymmetricDS to maintain consistency across systems."

SymmetricDS does support bidirectional file sync. If you query sym_file_snapshot on both sides, are there entries in both tables? If you make a new file change on the target, does it show up in sym_file_snapshot?
We believe you are missing some kind of configuration in your setup.

After some attempts, I realized that by declaring the corresponding triggers, router, and trigger_router on the client node, and then restarting the SymmetricDS server, it worked fine. Thanks for your interest. Greetings!
